# no results if setting more than 2 parameters to the querybuilder - laravel-doctrine/orm + Lumen + oracle

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, lumen

I am facing a strange problem trying to execute a simple request using laravel-doctrine/orm v1.2.5 on Lumen v5.2.7. with an Oracle database.

When I create a query with the query builder containing more than 2 parameters, I get no results, even though I am expecting a result set.

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('*')
    ->from('SYNCHS')
    ->where('SYNCHS.CLIENT_ID = :clientId')
    ->andWhere('SYNCHS.TOP_CLIENT_ID = :topClientId')
    ->andWhere('SYNCHS.ID = :synchId');

$queryBuilder->setParameter('clientId', $clientId)
    ->setParameter('topClientId', $topClientId)
    ->setParameter('synchId', $synchId);

echo $queryBuilder->getSQL();
var_dump($queryBuilder->getParameters());

$stmt = $queryBuilder->execute();
var_dump($stmt);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
dd($results);
```

If I comment any one of the where/addwhere clause, I end up with the expected result set, but if I have more than 2 parameters bound in the query, it returns nothing (of course it should return something with the passed parameters).

For every scenari:

1. I can see all my parameters are bound in the query builder `var_dump($queryBuilder->getParameters());`
2. Copy paste of the `echo $queryBuilder->getSQL();` in Toad (oracle) setting the parameters with the values displayed by the `var_dump($queryBuilder->getParameters());` give me 1 row (expected result). So I am sure that my query is correct.

I've looked for hours on google but no relevant result appeared for this problem. Thanks

Comment: what result set are you expecting

Comment: I am just expecting 1 row to be returned but I have none